# как к datetime прибавить time

Tags: python

Есть 2 переменных

```
print(datetime_1)
print(time_1)
```

их вывод:

```
2022-10-19 00:00:00
07:24:27
```

Как к datetime прибавить time, что бы получилось:

```
2022-10-19 07:24:27
```

?

datetime_1 и time_1 тянутся из бд

Comment: в каком виде они тянутся из бд? что выводит print(type(datetime_1)) и print(type(time_1))? Потому что то, что у вас выводится, похоже на строки, а не на datetime и time.

Comment: Результат должен быть в формате строки или datetime?

Comment: datetime_1 - <class 'datetime.datetime'> 
time_1- <class 'datetime.time'>
результат должен быть datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

```
combined_dateTime = datetime_1.combine(datetime_1, time_1)
print(combined_dateTime) #2022-10-19 07:24:27
```

Answer (score 0):

если в лоб, то так:

```
import datetime

dt1 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-10-19 00:00:00")
dt2 = datetime.time.fromisoformat("07:24:27")

res = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt1.timestamp() + 3600 * dt2.hour + 60 * dt2.minute + dt2.second)

print(res)
```